# R how to know if a library is effectively used?

Tags: r, libraries

I have a hudge code, and where all the libraries are attached in the begining of the code. Now, I'm cleaning a bit this code, removing parts of it / re-writting other.

I was wondering if there was a way to know if a specific library is used or not by the code (in order to clean the library part too)? I could list, for each library, all the functions that are attached, then search in the code that this function are not called, but it will become long. I could also remove this library and try to run the code, but I don't like this solution (not enough robust).

I'm sorry if the question have already been asked, but so far, I haven't found any solution :(.

Comment: You could remove all libraries and run the code and only add the ones it complains about... "I could check for each library that each function attached is not called," I don't understand that sentence... I usually use "require(sampleLibrary)" in each method for each library that is used, so I get a better overview and don't load libraries that are not required...

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid this is explicitly mentioned by the OP in the second paragraph as a non-possibility.

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid Yes, the way you do is also the way I prefer to do it, but I did'nt write this code (someone else did).
I don't like waiting for R to complain, that is why I asked this question. But if there is no other way to do it, I will follow this method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that sentence... Is it an official R package you use (the huge code) and what library are you talking about?

Comment: Nop, not an official package, just a simulation and post-processing code that a collegue of me did and that I'm supposed to re-use.
The libraries are  "ncdf", "chron", "reshape", "abind", "Rmisc", "solaR", "scales", "ggplot2", "e1071", "lubridate", "lattice", "plotrix"

Comment: I can imagine the code that parses the source files, finds all `require` and `library` calls with regex, lists all functions from those packages and then checks if any of them are used in the sources. It won't be very complex.